# File Download popup overwrites the alert popup

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

When the user clicks on the "Export to Excel" link, the standard "File download" dialog is presented to the user. [See here for an example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaO6n.jpg).

But before exporting the excel file, I want to display an alert popup.  But the Save dialog is obscuring the view of the alert popup.

How can I display the popup without it being obscured?

Here is my code...

```
dsResult = clsObj.getSearchResults_BL(detObj);

if (OrdDifference != null && OrdDifference.Any())
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.up, this.GetType(), "export", "alert('.....')", true);
   set(dsResult, strName);
}
else
{
  set(dsResult, strName);
}

private void set(DataSet ds, string strFileName)
{
    ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine();
    IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;
    application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2007;
    IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Create(1);
    IWorksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
    try
    {
        sheet.Name = strFileName;
        sheet.ImportDataTable(ds.Tables[0], true, 1, 1, -1, -1);

        ...

        workbook.SaveAs(strFileName, ExcelSaveType.SaveAsXLS, HttpContext.Current.Response, ExcelDownloadType.PromptDialog);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clean up the code to remove all the logic that's not specifically related to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.up, this.GetType(), "export", "alert('.....')", true);
set(dsResult, strName);
```

Because the `set` method in your program is writing to the Response Stream the call to `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` ends up doing nothing.

You need to do this on two steps:

```
if (OrdDifference != null && OrdDifference.Any())
{
   //Just do this, nothing more.
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.up, this.GetType(), "export", "alertUser('Some Message Here')", true);

}
```

Now define the `alertUser` function in Javascript:

```
function alertUser(message)
{
    alert(message);
    window.location='AccepServiceOrder.aspx?o=Export';
}
```

Now on `Page_Load` check for the `o` parameter in the query string

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(Request.QueryString["o"]!=null)
     { 
        dsResult = clsObj.getSearchResults_BL(detObj);
         set(dsResult, strName);
     }
}
```